# Multiprocessing nested loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I am very new to complicated coding in python but I want to improve my code to perform much better and much faster. Searching for that, I came across 'multiprocessing', which I tried to implement, but could not.

I have a process which requires me to run several loops and this is quite a bit time taking, like 160 hours for just one year (and I have 16 years to compute). I want to utilize multiple cores on the server and compute the process much faster (now I am using only a single core and my server had 48).

Below is the code:

```py
# My dataset
deficit_all.shape
Out: (5844, 400, 1440)

max_deficit_annual = np.zeros((16,400,1440))
int_year = 0

for year in tqdm(range(2000,2016)):
    for lat in tqdm(range(400)):
        for long in tqdm(range(1440)):
            if year%4 == 0:
                cummul_deficit = np.zeros(366)
                for i in tqdm(range(366)):
                    cummul_deficit[i] = deficit_all[i+int_year,lat,long] + cummul_deficit[i-1]
                    if cummul_deficit[i] < 0:
                        cummul_deficit[i] = 0
                    else:
                        continue
                #####print(np.nanmax(cummul_deficit))
                max_deficit_annual[year-2000,lat,long] = np.nanmax(cummul_deficit)

            else:
                cummul_deficit = np.zeros(365)
                for i in tqdm(range(365)):
                    cummul_deficit[i] = deficit_all[i+int_year,lat,long] + cummul_deficit[i-1]
                    if cummul_deficit[i] < 0:
                        cummul_deficit[i] = 0
                    else:
                        continue
                ######print(np.nanmax(cummul_deficit))
                max_deficit_annual[year-2000,lat,long] = np.nanmax(cummul_deficit)
            sleep(1)

    if year%4 == 0:
        int_year += 366
    else:
        int_year += 365
```

Is it possible for my code to use multiprocessing? or any other parallel computing option?

Comment: Why are you resetting cumulative deficit to zero when it goes below zero? Is this your business requirement?

Comment: Yes, the deficit can never be zero. So, zero is assigned as a minimum.

Comment: This is why you have not used `np.cumsum` function, I see. The way to approach this kind of problem is to get rid of for loops wherever possible. You are using Numpy you have to vectorize operations(work with matrix operations instead of loops that is).